# How to use MSMQ over http through the respective WCF binding?

Tags: wcf, http, msmq

We have a one way connection between an agent and the server via MSMQ. I am trying to move it to MSMQ over http.

Now, MSMQ is integrated with IIS on the server side - I made sure to check the respective option when installed MSMQ. But I am puzzled what to do next. I mean, the endpoint address has no indication that MSMQ should be over http.

The relevant agent (which acts as a client) configuration is:

```
<client>
  <endpoint name="WcfOneWayDataPortal"
            address="net.msmq://server/private/nc_queue"
            contract="Shunra.Common.Contract.IWcfOneWayPortal"
            binding="netMsmqBinding"
            bindingConfiguration="Msmq" />
</client>
<bindings>
  <netMsmqBinding>
    <binding name="Msmq" durable="true" useActiveDirectory="false" exactlyOnce="false"
             receiveErrorHandling="Fault" maxReceivedMessageSize="2147483647">
      <security mode="None">
        <transport msmqAuthenticationMode="None" msmqProtectionLevel="None" />
      </security>
    </binding>
  </netMsmqBinding>
</bindings>
```

And the server's one is:

```
<services>
  <service name="Shunra.Common.Csla.WcfOneWayPortal" >
    <endpoint contract="Shunra.Common.Contract.IWcfOneWayPortal"
              binding="netMsmqBinding"
              bindingConfiguration="Msmq"
              address="net.msmq://server/private/nc_queue"/>
  </service>
</services>
<bindings>
  <netMsmqBinding>
    <binding name="Msmq" durable="true" useActiveDirectory="false" exactlyOnce="false"
             maxReceivedMessageSize="2147483647">
      <security>
        <transport msmqAuthenticationMode="None" msmqProtectionLevel="None"/>
      </security>
    </binding>
  </netMsmqBinding>
</bindings>
```

Comment: Found the answer - http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa395217.aspx

Comment: (Note: it is normal for link-only answers to be converted to a comment here. If you'd like to present it in an answer, please post the link plus a summary of it, so that a summary of the solution can be appreciated without visiting the link.)