# What is the actual MSMQ address used by the respective WCF binding?

Tags: wcf, msmq

This question is related to [this one](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4499091/how-to-use-msmq-over-http-through-the-respective-wcf-binding).

Given that WCF binding uses `net.msmq://` URL, for instance `net.msmq://server/private/nc_queue`, how can one know what is the actual MSMQ address to which this URL is translated? Is there some kind of a trace that can be activated? Or an external tool that would help one capture the address?

Thanks.

**EDIT1**

OK, I owe a clarification. One can talk directly to MSMQ through the respective .NET API. In the case of MSMQ over its native port 1801, I would use this MSMQ address:

```
FormatName:Direct=OS:server\private$\nc_queue
```

When MSMQ is configured over HTTP, the address changes to something like this:

```
FormatName:Direct=http://server/msmq/nc_queue
```

But the WCF binding uses a standard URL to describe the address, like:

```
net.msmq://server/private/nc_queue
```

So, how can I know what is the actual MSMQ address (the one with the FormatName) to which the `net.msmq://` is translated?

Answer (score 2):

I don't really understand your question.... if you use the WCF `netMsmqBinding`, you're basically dropping off MSMQ messages into an MSMQ queue. So what you really have is a **queue name** that you're dealing with - not a URL.....

```
net.msmq://server/private/nc_queue
```

This translates into a MSMQ private queue called `nc_queue` on `server` - so what is it really that you're trying to do?? I'm not getting it..... care to clarify??

In the meantime, check out Tom Hollander's three-part blog post series on MSMQ, WCF and IIS:

- [MSMQ, WCF and IIS: Getting them to play nice (part 1 of 3)](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/tomholl/archive/2008/07/12/msmq-wcf-and-iis-getting-them-to-play-nice-part-1.aspx)
- [MSMQ, WCF and IIS: Getting them to play nice (part 2 of 3)](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/tomholl/archive/2008/07/12/msmq-wcf-and-iis-getting-them-to-play-nice-part-2.aspx)
- [MSMQ, WCF and IIS: Getting them to play nice (part 3 of 3)](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/tomholl/archive/2008/07/12/msmq-wcf-and-iis-getting-them-to-play-nice-part-3.aspx)

**Update:** I think I'm beginning to understand your issues - if you're using the WCF `netMsmqBinding`, you're connecting to MSMQ directly - this is **not** "MSMQ-over-HTTP". If you want to set up and use MSMQ-over-HTTP from a WCF client, from what I understand, you'd be talking to a straight regular HTTP service, so you'd have to use `basicHttpBinding` (or `wsHttpBinding`) - **not** the specific `netMsmqBinding`.

Comment: I doubt that. wsHttpBinding does not have the MSMQ specific parameters.

Comment: @Mark: yes, but if you expose "MSMQ over HTTP", then we're really talking about a HTTP endpoint you need to talk to....

Comment: @Mark: using the netMsmqBinding goes directly into the MSMQ queue - doesn't support "over HTTP", I would believe....

Comment: I think you are wrong - http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa395217.aspx. Anyway, the question is more about the tracing. How can I trace the process?