# Using MSMQ over HTTP. How to address the queue?

Tags: c#, .net, msmq

I'm currently trying to use MSMQ with C# and .NET in order to achieve IPC.
I am trying to understand how it works, and I'm quite confused about the [differences between Path name and Format name when accessing MSMQ queues](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/johnbreakwell/archive/2009/02/26/difference-between-path-name-and-format-name-when-accessing-msmq-queues.aspx).
I've found some similar issues in the following posts:

1. [MSMQ calls over HTTP not reaching destination queue](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9488010/msmq-calls-over-http-not-reaching-destination-queue)
2. [How to setup MSMQ server so that it can be accessed over the Internet](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19156136/how-to-setup-msmq-server-so-that-it-can-be-accessed-over-the-internet)
3. [How to use MSMQ over http through the respective WCF binding?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4499091/how-to-use-msmq-over-http-through-the-respective-wcf-binding)

However, they're all using MSMQ and WCF, and I don't want to use WCF for now.

What I want to achieve is the following:

**Client:** Sends data to the queue through **http**.

**Server:** Receives data from the queue through **http**.

My point here is that I want that either *server, client and the queue* to be hosted in potentially different computers. (For now I'm testing everything in the same machine).

Here I have the following code, which demonstrates what I have in mind:

First, I create the queue:

```
if(!System.Messaging.MessageQueue.Exists(@".\Private$\SimplestExamplePrivateQueue");
    System.Messaging.MessageQueue.Create(@".\Private$\SimplestExamplePrivateQueue");
```

**Client code:**

Then, at the client side, I have a callback function which is invoked when the user presses a button in order to send a message.

```
private void button1_Click(object sender, System.EventArgs e)
{
    try
    {           
        // Create a connection to the queue
        System.Messaging.MessageQueue mq = new System.Messaging.MessageQueue(@"FormatName:Direct=http://localhost/msmq/Private$/SimplestExamplePrivateQueue");

        // Create a point object to send
        Point myPoint = new Point (Convert.ToInt32(textBox2.Text), Convert.ToInt32(textBox3.Text)) ;

        // Send object 
        mq.Send (myPoint) ;
    }

    // Catch the exception that signals all types of error
    // from the message queueing subsystem. Report error
        // to the user. 
    catch (System.Messaging.MessageQueueException mqx)
    {
        MessageBox.Show (mqx.Message) ;
    }
```

Everything until here works fine.

**Server code:**

Then, I have a button which invokes a callback function to synchronously read one message from the queue at the server side:

```
private void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    try
    {
        // Create a connection to the queue
        var mq = new MessageQueue(@"Direct=http://localhost/msmq/Private$/SimplestExamplePrivateQueue");

        // Set the queue's formatter to decode Point objects
        mq.Formatter = new XmlMessageFormatter(new[] {typeof (Point)});

        // Receive message synchronously
        Message msg = mq.Receive();

        // Convert received message to object that we think was sent
        var pt = (Point) msg.Body;

        // Display it to the user
        MessageBox.Show(pt.ToString(), "Received Point");
    }

    // Report any exceptions to the user. A timeout would cause such
    // an exception
    catch (Exception x)
    {
        MessageBox.Show(x.Message);
    }
}
```

In my (limited) understanding of MSMQ, this should work. However, when I call `Message msg = mq.Receive();` I get the following exception:

```
The specified format name does not support the requested operation. For example, a direct queue format name cannot be deleted.
```

And the Stack Trace:

```
at System.Messaging.MessageQueue.MQCacheableInfo.get_ReadHandle()
   at System.Messaging.MessageQueue.StaleSafeReceiveMessage(UInt32 timeout, Int32 action, MQPROPS properties, NativeOverlapped* overlapped, ReceiveCallback receiveCallback, CursorHandle cursorHandle, IntPtr transaction)
   at System.Messaging.MessageQueue.ReceiveCurrent(TimeSpan timeout, Int32 action, CursorHandle cursor, MessagePropertyFilter filter, MessageQueueTransaction internalTransaction, MessageQueueTransactionType transactionType)
   at System.Messaging.MessageQueue.Receive()
   at InternetQueueingRecipient.Form1.button1_Click(Object sender, EventArgs e) in c:\Users\felipedalcin\Documents\MSMQ\MSMQandNET\InternetQueuing\InternetQueueingRecipient\Form1.cs:line 85
```

Does anyone have an idea of how I could debug this or even if what I want to do is achievable by those means?

Comment: You cannot receive messages over HTTP

Answer (score 0):

Direct format names that specify the HTTP or HTTPS protocol cannot be used to peek at or receive messages, only to send them