# Why do I need to use WCF to consume an MSMQ?

Tags: c#, wcf, asp.net-web-api, msmq

I'd like to communicate from my web app to an endpoint on a different tier via MSMQ. I've found examples of how to do this by binding with WCF, but not how to with WebAPI.

Why do I have to use WCF?

Are they any other alternatives?

Comment: You don't.  You use the MSMQ client library in the System.Messaging namespace.  Why would you use WebAPI or WCF?

Comment: @Amy WCF allows a level of encapsulation around the specific protocol, allowing OP to seamlessly switch to other one way communication protocols without changing code, e.g. IBM Websphere MQ (MQ Series).

Comment: What makes you think you do need to?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Other than [WCF's netmsmqBinding](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.servicemodel.netmsmqbinding(v=vs.110).aspx), you could also obviously use the more native [System.Messaging.MessageQueue](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.messaging.messagequeue(v=vs.110).aspx) .Net classes to read and write directly from queues. However, it sounds like you are trying to pull messages from a client such as a browser?

Although you can [send messages to MSMQ via Http](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms701477(v=vs.85).aspx), you can't [receive messages over Http directly](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19414046/using-msmq-over-http-how-to-address-the-queue).

So *TL;DR* I believe you will need to write your own capability to receive messages via HTTP / REST etc, e.g. via a WebApi controller action which reads exactly one message and returns same. In doing so you will likely lose any transactional boundary across queue messages.